# Magento Configuarble Product Issues

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am just trying to work out pros and cons for the configurable product option. I have a shoe which is available in different colours and sizes. It makes sense to make both the size and colour configurable. The have two issues with this:

1. On a list page I can only show one option, and not show all the colours as individual products
2. I can't seem to link directly to a configurable product with the colour attribute set

Does anyone know a way of overcoming the above issues?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Color swatches http://www.venustheme.com/configurable-swatches-guide-for-magento-1-9-1/ allows You to use configurable product options in catalog, but it is extremly slow. For better performance You can use https://github.com/wigman/AjaxSwatches.

Another idea is asynchronous popup with product options in catalog, but I don't know any extension for this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is exactly what I am using at the moment. The issue I have is I cant link to a product with a colour option set. As an example I want to link from a blog article to a particular product and go straight to the red option